# Show that there exists a path of class $C^1$ between $x$ and $y$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $H$ be an arc connectedness (a subset of $R^n$) , and both $x$ and $y$ components of $H$
>
> Show that there exists a path of class $C^1$ between $x$ and $y$

I feel it's not true,
if we take for $H$ the graph of a function nowhere differentiable and we have $x '(t)$ somewhere in the middle of your path $t \mapsto (x (t), y (t) )$, then it bugue violently we must have $x'(u) \geq \varepsilon> 0$ on any open interval, so $x$ locally admits a differentiable inverse function, then there is nowhere differentiable on this interval. So you're required to have $x=0$, and suddenly it bugue also because $x$ is necessarily constant.

> If I add $H$ is open, does it work ?

I feel the answer is yes, but I cannot prove it.

Thanks

Comment: What is $H$? If it is just a topological space, then how do you define $C^1$-smooth paths. It it is a subspace of $R^n$ then you have to specify its regularity, otherwise you can take a fractal curve which contains no smooth paths. If $H$ is open in $R^n$ then just use approximation of continuous functions by smooth functions (Weierstrass theorem).

Comment: @studiosus Yes H is a topological space, I edited, H is arc connectedness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $X$ is an arbitrary topological space, there is no notion of a $C^1$-map 
to $H$. Thus, I assume that $H$ is a subset of $R^n$ for some $n$ with the subspace topology. For $H$ open in $R^n$, the [Weierstrass approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) shows that you can approximate any continuous path in $H$ by a smooth one (with the same end-points). If $H$ is not required to be open then the answer is negative as we can take $H$ to be a planar Jordan curve of positive Hausdorff measure locally everywhere (say, Koch snowflake). Every subarc of this curve will have infinite length. Thus, there are no smooth nonconstant functions from $[0,1]$ to such $H$.

Edit. Suppose that $f: [0,1]\to R$ is  continuous function and $f_n: [0,1]\to R$ 
is a approximating sequence. I assume that $f(0)=a\ne b=f(1)$ and will leave you to work out the case of equality. For $a_n=f_n(0), b_n=f_n(1)$ consider affine  functions  $h_n: R\to R$ 
$$
h_n(a_n)=a, h_n(b_n)=b. 
$$
You can write down these functions explicitly and verify that they converge (uniformly on compacts) to the identity function. Therefore, the compositions 
$$
g_n=h_n\circ f_n
$$
have fixed values at $0$ and $1$ and converge uniformly to $f$.

Comment: you are right, is a subset of $R^n$, but I know Weierstrass theorem but are you sure about the statement : with the same end-points ?

Comment: Sure: Take any approximation and then postcompose with a linear function to ensure that the end-points are fixed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I tried twice without success. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice answer, for Weierstrass we can do like this : Let  $F : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, by Stone-Weierstrass there exist $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $\|P-f\|_\infty \leq \varepsilon$. Plus, let $Q(X) = P(X) + (f(0)-P(0))(1-X) + (f(1)-P(1))X$, we have $\|P-Q\|_\infty \leq 2\varepsilon$ and$ Q(i) = f(i)$ for $i=0,1.$